# Is it possible to use Celery almost out-of-box with an external API?

Tags: celery

I find Celery would be ideal candidate for consuming async events from multiple rabbitmq queues and spreading the workload over an internal api.

Would there be some kind of out-of-the-box configuration that could dynamically route jobs either according named queues or messages to the external API, with as little configuration as number of workers per queues, maybe TTLs for external api calls, acknowledgement, dead letter exchange, ...

I'm not that much into Python and the aim would to be to only have to maintain configuration.

Comment: Title : external api => means not Python

Comment: spreading the workload over an internal api => means on the same internal network

Comment: Currently reading about the celery-connectors project : https://pypi.org/project/celery-connectors/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Celery does not consume arbitrary RabbitMQ messages - only those that are Celery specific so I do not think Celery is suitable for what you described above. On the other hand, [kombu](https://kombu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (which is one of Celery projects) could be used for what you are saying. Or even lower-level - the [py-amqp](https://github.com/celery/py-amqp) library (which also under Celery umbrella).

Answer (score 0):

Celery WILL consume all messages from the queue, but to force it to process them, you'll have to translate your messages to a specific JSON format, which Celery accepts, otherwise messages will be just discard

Generally, Celery may be suitable for making external API calls in async manner, but not for messages routing
I would suggest you to take a look at `Apache Camel` framework, it implements EIP, including dead lettering and message's TTL